# Why can't I shift the structure array by 1 element?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, 2d, shift

I'm trying to shift an array of structures by 1 element and then erase the first element but for some reason there is a missing element on the print out. At first it looks like its working where most of the elements are shifted however around the 14th entry there should be a 33 and that's not there? Why is this?

```
struct msr{
int a;
int b;
int c;};

struct msr msr_struc[20];

int main(){
  int add_val = 0;

      //Initialise structure elements with some data
  for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    msr_struc[i].b = i+20;

            //Shift the structure by 1 element
    memmove(&msr_struc[add_val+1], &msr_struc[add_val], (20-add_val-1)*sizeof(double));
            //Reset the first entry
    memset(&msr_struc[0], 0, sizeof(msr_struc[0]));

            //Print results
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        printf("strc: %d \n", msr_struc[i].b);

    printf("MISSING: %d \n", msr_struc[14].b);


return 0;
 }


strc: 0 
strc: 20 
strc: 21 
strc: 22 
strc: 23 
strc: 24 
strc: 25 
strc: 26 
strc: 27 
strc: 28 
strc: 29 
strc: 30 
strc: 31 
strc: 32 
strc: 34 
strc: 35 
strc: 36 
strc: 37 
strc: 38 
strc: 39 
MISSING: 34
```

Comment: *undefined behavior*

Comment: Where'd you get `sizeof(double)`? Try `sizeof(struct msr)`.

Comment: And where is that 14 from?

Comment: sizeof(struct msr) worked :) Cheers for that. I was looking at a number of examples and I got sizeof(double) from one.

Comment: Do not use `sizeof(type)`, use `sizeof msr_struc[0]` and not worry about matching the type.